# How to record device audio output (record while listening songs online)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, voice-recording

How to record songs while listening (from online source) on Android 4.4/Nexus 5.

I am not able to find any apps for this. All voice recorder apps seems to be supporting only background sound, and not the device sound output (in earphone).